# Trainamento de Objeto no OpenCV (Certo ou Errado)

Tags: opencv

Ola Pessoal estou em um projeto de computação visual aqui da empresa e queria saber dos mais experientes no assunto se estou fazendo o certo para treinar um objeto.

Eu li muito e estudei o assunto a respeito testei diversas frameworks e cheguei a conclusao de usar OpenCV. So que os resultados do treinamento no meu ShellPrompt estao dando diferentes dos exemplos que vejo nos tutoriais e videos pela net.

Estou treinando 80 imagem de 80x54 (imagens positivas) e 160 imagens (negativas)
fazendo a seguintes passos :

1-Create Samples

```
C:\OPENCV\v3.3.1\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_createsamples.exe -info C:\Trainner002\pos\pos.txt -vec C:\Trainner002\data\vector_rg.vec -bg C:\Trainner002\neg\infofile.txt -num 80 -w 80 -h 54
```

2-Train Cascade

```
C:\OPENCV\v3.3.1\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data C:\Trainner002\cascade -vec C:\Trainner002\data\vector_rg.vec -bg C:\Trainner002\neg\infofile.txt -numPos 80 -numNeg 160 -mode ALL -numStages 25 -w 80 -h 54 -featureType LBP
```

3- Resultado do treinamento no shellprompt

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu treinamento da uma linha so por estagio e eu ja observei muitos tutoriais de pessoas fazendo treinamento de object detection mas da varias linhas por estagio.

aqui esta alguns exemplos iguais ao meu na verdade eu estou seguindo os exemplo que encontrei e o resultado e diferente.

http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

reparem no resultado do treinamento dele, o resultado e parecido com o meu porem a tabela dele da mais resultados do que a minha que e uma linha por tabela. Porem meu treinamento gera todos os arquivo corretamente, nesta configuração.

Estou correto sera ?
Sera uma versão do OpenCV ?
Sara as configurações que estão erradas no traincascade ?

Fico no aguardo!

Comment: Já no texto do tutorial que vc está utilizando, bem depois dos "resultados", consta o seguinte: "*Each row represents a feature that is being trained and contains some output about its HitRatio and FalseAlarm ratio. If a training stage only selects a few features (e.g. N = 2) then its possible something is wrong with your training data.*". Ou seja: 1) isso não são resultados, são as características (haar features) encontradas e úteis na classificação dos dados.

Comment: 2) Se vc está obtendo só 1 delas, é provável que "há algo errado" com os seus dados. Eu diria que eles são pouco representativos do objeto no mundo real ou, mais provável, que as imagens tenham pouca variação. Vc capturou imagens em diferentes orientações, com diferentes fundos, etc? Procure melhorar seus dados de entrada para o treinamento.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado! pelo comentário e ajuda, na verdade sao documentos mais especificadamente o lado de traz do RG tenho varios RGs nos dados de entrada de 100px por 64px pois se eu aumentar um pouco vai dar estouro de memoria... estou treinando 119 faces de RG por 236 de imagens negativas.  Voce acha que eu deveria aumentar as imagens positivas ? ou seja as 110px por 640px ?

Comment: Honestamente eu não sei te responder. Esse tipo de processo é meio por tentativa e erro. Vc tem várias imagens de RG em diferentes rotações? O que eu disse de variabilidade era isso mesmo: diferentes orientações e tals, não necessariamente ter mais imagens. Muito embora ter mais imagens ajude.

Comment: Outra coisa: se vc quer detectar RGs, não tem abordagens mais fáceis (e rápidas)? Já tentou com limiarização? Posso estar enganado, mas dependendo do que vc quer fazer com os RGs (e de como pode capturar as imagens), usar Haar pode ser como usar um canhão pra matar uma formiga.

Comment: na verdade não tentei a limiarização, o que seria isso ? so para ver se estamos com a mesmo pensamento, no meu creio que limiarizacao seria o fato de pegar a imagem deixa-la em grayscale e depois aplicar o threshold (limiarizacao ou binarizacao em fim) para entao detectar o retangulo do RG ? 

Sobre as outras questoes eu pego as imagens scaneadas que recebo pode ter RG frente e verso ou ate mesmo o RG junto com CPF e outros documento, e estou deixando na horizontal sabe, todas elas vem scaneada com o fundo branco da folha sulfite ou do fundo branco da tampa do aparelho de scanner

Comment: O que na sua opniao seria mais pratico ou ate mesmo preciso talvez ? para  reconhecimento de documento. Aqui na empresa para este projeto estudamos a possibilidade de usar TensorFlow ou OpenCV,  tivemos a ideia de que com reconhecimento do objeto no caso o documento seria de bom tamanho para darmos um crop desde que reconhecido e ate mesmo deixa-lo na horizontal depois de reconhecido é obvio e passar para segunda analise que é de OCR em fim. 
Mas precisamos desta primeira etapa sabe.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70019/discussion-between-luiz-vieira-and-rodrigo).

Comment: Nos precisamos mais ou menos disso, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056592/how-to-detect-document-from-a-picture-in-opencv uma pena por que nao funcionou aqui eu consegui fazer esse exemplo mas aqui o fundo e branco sabe e o maior retangulo detectado fica sendo as bordas da folha maior no exemplo do cara ele esta sobre um fundo colorido o que facilitou a detecção do objeto, precisamos disso para RG, CPF, em fim nosso piloto e o RG